# How to make a deep copy of an entire QDomDocument

Tags: c++, qt, qtxml

I want to create a deep copy of a `QDomDocument` in an xml model in order to allow the user to later restore the document to its original state. The [QDomDocument documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdomdocument.html#QDomDocument-4) says that this can be achieved by using `cloneNode()`. However, `cloneNode()` returns a `QDomNode`, not a `QDomDocument`, and I can't seem to figure out how how to properly add it to a new document.

I've tried:

```
QDomDocument copy;
copy.importNode(existingDocument.cloneNode(true),true);
```

and

```
QDomDocument copy;
copy.appendChild(existingDocument.cloneNode(true),true);
```

but neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a QDomNode, you can use its [toDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomnode.html#toDocument) function.

Assuming **QDomNode node** is the node returned from cloneNode()

```
QDomDocument newDocument = node.toDocument();
```